# Дата и время, которая приходит из UseState отображается неправильно

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime, react-hook

```
Как не преобразую в new Date(), изчезает весь HTML и соответственно выдает ошибку. Подскажите, как преобразовать дату, которая приходит из стейта selected => '2022-10-26T15:44:01.000Z
', в => 'ДД-ММ-ГГ | ЧЧ:ММ'
```

*Объект в стейте selected находится объект: {id: 1, date: '2022-10-26T15:44:01.000Z', ...} и приходит все это из БД через бэкэнд. Нужен именно тот вариант, который нужно в клиенте преобразовать а не сразу из бэка!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './ExtendedNews.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

const ExtendedNews = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const[selected, setSelected] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/myNews')
        .then(response => {
            setSelected(response.data.find((obj) => {
                return obj.id === +id;
            }));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        $('.extendedNews').hide();
        $('.extendedNews').fadeIn();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='extendedNews'>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="postWrap">
                    <h1 className="pageName">{selected && selected.title}</h1>
                    <span className="date">{selected && selected.date}</span>
                    <img src={`${selected && selected.img}`} alt="newsImg" />
                    <div className='textWrap'>{selected && selected.content}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExtendedNews;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const str = '2022-10-26T15:44:01.000Z';

function convertDate(str) {
  const data = new Date(str);
  return data.getDate() + '-' +
    (data.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    data.getFullYear() + ' | ' +
    data.getHours() + ':' +
    data.getMinutes();
}

console.log(convertDate(str))

// Если время будет некорректно отображаться, то можно попробовать сделать поправку на временную зону

function convertDate2(str) {
  let data = new Date(str);
  const corr = data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
  if (corr) {
    data = new Date(data.getTime() + corr);
  }
  return data.getDate() + '-' +
    (data.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    data.getFullYear() + ' | ' +
    data.getHours() + ':' +
    data.getMinutes();
}

console.log(convertDate2(str))
```

Передайте ваш selected.date в такую функцию и она вернет время в виде строки в нужном вам формате.

Пример строки из вашего кода

```
<span className="date">{selected && convertDate(selected.date)}</span>
```

Если возможны случаи, когда selected.date пусто, то допишите необходимы проверки в функции и возврат "дефолтного" значения.