# Как в JS через Date.parse() посчитать разницу во времени игнорируя переходы на зимнее/летнее?

Tags: javascript

```js
alert((Date.parse('30-Oct-2022 04:04:37')-Date.parse('30-Oct-2022 03:04:37'))/1000/60/60);
```

Этот код выводит "2", хотя прошел только час. Все из-за перехода на зимнее время. Как можно сделать так, чтобы код просто считал разницу, игнорируя все эти летне-зимние переходы?

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться [смещением часового пояса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460831/%d0%94%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-usestate-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/1460844#1460844), `getTimezoneOffset()`, вдруг поможет.

Comment: В смысле "2"? У меня он выводит "1" как положено.

Comment: мы находимся в разных часовых поясах, Date.parse к этому привязан, по этому в каждой точке мира будет свой результат. я бы хотел чтобы оно считало одинаково вне зависимости от часового пояса

Comment: @SwaD спасибо, функция помогла, решение с кодом добавлю сюда

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertDate(str) {
  let data = new Date(str);
  const corr = data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
  if (corr) {
    data = new Date(data.getTime() - corr);
  }
  return data;
}

alert((convertDate('30-Oct-2022 04:04:37')-convertDate('30-Oct-2022 03:04:37'))/1000/60/60);
```