# Как получить дату компа в миллисекундах?

Tags: javascript

Написал для этого JS код:

```js
let chas = "60000"; // 1минута это 60000 миллисекунд
var now = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();    //в перем now получаем смещение UTC относит моего пояса в минутах например -120
var millisek_smesh = Number(chas) * Number(now); //в перем millisek_smesh получаем смещение UTC относит моего пояса в миллисек
var date = new Date();
var mil = date.getTime(); // текущую дату в миллисекундах, но еще не сместил
var millisek_smesh_itog = Number(millisek_smesh) + Number(mil); // Изменую текущую дату на смещение  
[[ITOG]] = millisek_smesh_itog
```

По итогу в переменой ITOG дата в миллисекундах меньше на 4 часа от той что должна получится. Где ошибка?

Вот например у меня пояс UTC+2 и на моем компе в 03.12.2022 14:34 этот  JS выдаёт значение в миллисекундах: 1670063686503 , что по факту равняется 03.12.2022 10:34:46,503

Comment: Вот тут описывал, [как можно сместить временную зону](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460831/1460844/1460844) - возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Сам разобрался. Вот готовый JS код может кому-то будет полезно:
let chas = "60000";
var now = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();    //now -120
var millisek_smesh = Number(chas) * Number(now);
var date = new Date();
var mil = date.getTime();

if (millisek_smesh < 0) {
  var millisek_smesh_itog = Number(mil) - Number(millisek_smesh);
} else {
  var millisek_smesh_itog = Number(mil) + Number(millisek_smesh);
}

[[ITOG]] = millisek_smesh_itog