# Почему в дате сдвиг -3 часа вместо -2 часа?

Tags: javascript, время, часовые-пояса

Используя JS создаю дату: **22 июля 19:46:27:40**

Причем на компе имею часовой пояс: UTC+2:00

```js
var date = new Date(2022, 6, 22, 19, 46, 27, 40);
console.log(date)
```

Результат:

[image]

Дата создаётся 16:46 , а должно быть 17:46.

Почему (см скриншот) дата создаётся со сдвигом на -3 часа вместо -2?

Comment: Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос: [сдвиг времени по часовому поясу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460831/%d0%94%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-usestate-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/1460844#1460844)

Comment: Летнее время? У используемого часового пояса оно применяется?

Comment: Покажите `date.getTimezoneOffset()`. Ну и `date.toString()`

Comment: @qwertiy 
в моей временной зоне переход был:
На зимнее время Воскресенье, 30 октября 2022 года в 4:00 На час назад

Comment: Ну а июль это на 3 месяца раньше октября

Comment: @andreymal как только поставил var date = new Date(2022, 11, 22, 19, 46, 27, 40); 
то показало сдвиг на -2 часа ...видимо проблема была из-за того что июле часы еще не меняли, а сейчас зимой (декабрь) часы поменяли на час назад