# Как получить разницу дат?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть две переменные в которых находятся дата время часовой пояс и тд, разница в них 30 секунд, как отнять их друг от друга , чтобы в итоге вывелось 00:30 ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         first: new Date(),
         second: new Date()
      }
   },
   methods: {
      ShowTime() {
         this.second.setSeconds(this.second.getSeconds() + 30)
         console.log('first - ' + ' ' + this.first);
         console.log('second - ' + ' ' + this.second);
         console.log('result - ' + ' ' + this.first - this.second)
      }
   },
   computed: {
      console: () => console,
   },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
      <button @click="ShowTime()">Show Time</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460831/1460844#1460844) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474583/1474591#1474591)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример плюшевый такой. Но думаю если разберетесь можете подстроить под себя)

```
const date = '2023-03-18 20:29:30';
const date2 = '2023-03-18 20:30:00';

const ms = Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date);
//Парсим дату и получаем общее время в миллисекундах. Далее базовая математика

console.log('00:' + ms / 1000); // 00:30
```